# Add footer with link in list of suggestions in autocomplete material angular

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm building a website using the (awesome looking) [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest). I am now using the [Autocomplete Component](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete) and I would like to add a fixed footer to the list of suggestions. Something like you can see in the image below, in which Pinterest adds twitter and google+ to the footer of the user search suggestions:

[image]

I tried to add a footer in the html md-autocomplete component:

```
<md-content layout-padding="" layout="column">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" md-min-length="0" placeholder="e-mail of naam " md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
            <md-item-template>
                <span class="item-title">
                    <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon>
                    <span> {{item.name}} </span>
                </span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-item-template>
                <footer><a href="">Some link</a></footer>   
            </md-item-template>
        </md-autocomplete>
    </form>
</md-content>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, nothing gets displayed. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNRVOz?editors=101) is the working example of the Material Autocomplete.

Does anybody know how I can add a fixed footer to the suggestions of the Angular Material Autocomplete? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Why the minus for this question? Is it not clear or is it something else

Comment: By "fixed footer" do you mean some default sugestions that show up at the bottom of the list regardless of the query?

Comment: Could you show the code for `ctrl.querySearch()` ? I have solution in mind that depends on what you might be doing there.

Comment: I dont think it has something to do with ctrl.querySearch() because this function makes the http call. I think some li element has to be added to the md-autocomplete component. This generates the list of suggestions.

Comment: Im not saying there's an issue there... The idea i had was to modify that function to always return the results + the fixed items even if the result is empty, but i didnt want to propose this without know what other implications that might have.

Comment: @kramer65 , H_C, it's not a difficult change to make. The code is rather transparent...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - good tot hear that. Would hou have any idea how?

Comment: @kramer65, in angular-material.js, you will want to alter `mdAutocomplete` to allow source for the footer. Then you should re-write `mdAutocompleteListItem` to reference this data and recompile the directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can ad additional template to `md-autocomplete`.
I believe that `md-autocomplete` clean up the selection list, and rebuilding it by repeating `md-item-template`

Thus, it's better to add additional data at the end of your search.

Here is the example.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGyLXP?editors=101

Controller parts

```
self.fixedOnes = [
  {'name'      : 'FIXED1', type: 'fixed'},
  {'name'      : 'FIXED2', type: 'fixed'},
  {'name'      : 'FIXED3', type: 'fixed'}
];
```

Html part

```
<md-autocomplete  ...
  md-items="item in (ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText).concat(ctrl.fixedOnes))" ... >
    <md-item-template>
      <div ng-class="{fixed:item.type=='fixed'}">
        <span> {{item.name}} </span>
      </div>
    </md-item-template>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

-------------  EDIT -----------------------
For, different style and contents, you can use `ng-class`, `ng-if`, of `ng-show` wisely since the contents of `md-item-template` are compiled.

I have updated the above answer for fixed ones to have different style.

Comment: no html injected there will be compiled. You have to change the directive to compile the "footer", which defeats the idea of being a functional footer. Also, your footer acts as a select-able choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how would I be able to style the extra items different from the regular items?

Comment: updated my answer for different style of extra items.

Comment: you can get a real footer by re-writing mdAutoComplete